# What is Law($Z$) under $\mu$ for a random variable $Z$, and distribution $\mu$?

Tags: probability-theory

Is it simply the probability measure $A\in\sigma(\mathbb{R})\mapsto\mu(Z^{-1}A)$? (Or correspondingly whatever the range of $Z$ might be.)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.